# Fatal error: Call to a member function setView() in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

i just downloaded the zend framework (full version ) and copied the zend library inside the library folder , but still getting this error

Fatal error: Call to a member function setView() on a non-object in /var/www/html/webkul/zf_1.8b1_app/application/Bootstrap.php on line 16

please advice any working tutorial on how to setup zend framework in linux environment

regards

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initView()
    {
        // Initialize view
        $view = new Zend_View();
        $view->doctype('XHTML1_STRICT');
        $view->headTitle('My Project');
        $view->env = APPLICATION_ENV;

        // Add it to the ViewRenderer
        $viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper(
            'ViewRenderer'
        );
        $viewRenderer->setView($view);

        // Return it, so that it can be stored by the bootstrap
        return $view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Btw, why are you doing: `$view->env = APPLICATION_ENV;`? You should not remap a constant which is globally available, it can mess up your code and make introspection difficult for someone else.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Did none of the present answers help you?

Answer (score 0):

i don't like the notion of overriding the default bootstrap chain which including creating the view instance but i can suggest to retrieve the already created instance of View object
and i will suppose that you are using layout as well

```
$this -> bootstrap ('layout');
$layout = $this -> getResource ('layout');
$view = $layout -> getView();
$view->addHelperPath('Dagho/View/Helper', 'Dagho_View_Helper');
$view -> doctype('XHTML1_STRICT');
$view->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv('Content-Type',
        'text/html; charset=utf-8')
       ->appendHttpEquiv('Content-Language', 'en-US');;
$view->headLink(array('rel' => 'favicon',
        'href' => $view->baseUrl().'/img/favicon.ico'),
        'PREPEND');
$view -> headLink() -> prependStylesheet($view->baseUrl('/css/demo.css'))
        ->prependStylesheet($view->baseUrl('/css/text.css'))
        ->prependStylesheet($view->baseUrl('/css/960.css'))
        ->prependStylesheet($view->baseUrl('/css/reset.css'));

$view->headScript()->appendFile($view->baseUrl('js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js') , "text/javascript")
        ->appendFile($view->baseUrl('js/jquery-ui.min.js') , "text/javascript");
$view -> headTitle('WebSite title');
$view -> headTitle() -> setSeparator( ' : ' );
$trackerId = 'UA-XXXXXX-X';
$googleAnalytics = $view->GoogleAnalytics($trackerId);
Zend_Registry::set("view", $view);
return $view ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do a lot of that in the bootstrap class; Zend now does a lot of it for you. In application.ini, if you use the following line it will initialise the view for you:

```
resources.view[] = ""
```

You can also set things like doctype and other parameters there as well instead of calling $view->doctype():

```
resources.view.params.doctype = "XHTML1_STRICT"
```

If you do need to manipulate the view object in the bootstrap though:

```
protected function _initViewSetup()
{
    $this->bootstrap('view');
    $view = $this->getResource('view');
    $view->env = APPLICATION_ENV
}
```